# Logstash fills my hard drive with jruby temp directories

Tags: linux, logstash, elk

I'm running a Logstash service (Logstash OSS with OpenSearch Output Plugin, Version 7.16.3) locally on my PC. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04, and all the packages are up to date.

However, after a period of time, it creates a lot of directories with `jruby-` prefix in my `/tmp` directory and fills the free space on my hard disk. Does anybody have an idea about the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a known bug in Logstash according to [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-ruby-tmp-folders-temporary-solution/283793) and [there](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11051).

### Best Solution

According to the information on the second page, it was resolved after Logstash version 8.1.0. So, the best solution might be to upgrade Logstash to a version greater than 8.1.0.

### Hot Fix

If upgrading the package is impossible, there's a temporary solution on the first page. Create an executable shell file `/path/to/clean.sh` containing the following command:

```bash
find . -type d -name 'jruby*' -mtime +1 -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Then, run it periodically using the crontab utility. Open crontab file:

```bash
sudo crontab -e
```

and add the following line to it:

```
0 */12 * * * /path/to/clean.sh
```